# Using Linode as a proxy server wrapped in DNS to bypass paid internet services

Tags: proxy

I have a linode server that I use for development.

I was thinking of using that as a proxy server. I have noticed that most paid connections allow DNS queries but don't allow http until I pay them.

I verified this by flushing my dns cache and nslookup some random websites.

How do I create a proxy server that allows me to may be wrap my packets from my computer in DNS packets, relay to my linode server with ssh key authentication and act as a broker?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to tunnel everything through a proxy, you might as well just run a proxy straight up. DNS tunneling, as I understand it, is a way to get around content blocks - for example website blacklists and content filters, not get around sites allowing free dns but not content lookups.

As I understand it, you're probably taking the wrong approach to trying to solve the problem